# How to check if an item is already downloaded during search iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I am developing an app that allows user to browse/search books and download them.
There are 3 UITableView, download/search/browse

I want to show a 'download' button if not downloaded, otherwise, show 'open' button.
It's straight forward in download tableview, I just query and show all books from core data.

The server is stateless and don't know if the user has downloaded the book or not.

I am saving the downloaded books in core data. The downloads tableview using FetchedResultsController.

When user search/browse by category start a new REST request and use the responded JSON as in memory NSArray to back up the tableview to display the title and author name, etc.

The books list is large and server support some advanced search like using Acronym and sort by popularity. so download the entire list and perform search at local requires more work.

What would be a good way to update determine if a book is downloaded in search view? query core data base each time in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in main thread sounds expensive. 
I also want to update the UI status in real time when a background download finishes, so modify the JSON after download did not work either

Thanks

Comment: Need a bit additional info. Are you using FetchedResultsController? Is the JSON data stored into CoreData or just in whatever model you have in memory?

Comment: Thanks, the questions is edited based on you suggestion. I am using FetchedResultsController in downloads tab. search json data are in memory not in CoreData, but this can change if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list of books is small (small enough that you can download it off the server in one go), you could probably get away with building the model for it in memory. Try querying the server, amending the response with CoreData results (all in the background), then tell the `UITableView` to reload itself (in the UI thread).

Pseudocode to illustrate:

```
dispatch_async(..., ^{
  [server requestData:param onComplete:^(NSDictionary* result){
    NSArray* someResult = [moc executeFetchRequest:...];
    NSArray* tableViewData = [mybusinesslogic mergeServerResult:result 
                              withCoreDataResult:someResult];
    myTableViewController.tableViewData = tableViewData;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [myTableViewController.tableView reloadData];
    });
  }];
});
```

Comment: do you mean I save the query results in CoreData too?

Answer (score 0):

Doing core data query for each cell is expensive. So Do a single query, then just match it in memory. If books have some sort of easily matchable id. Perhaps something like this:

1) Get the responded JSON NSArray. (maybe parse out the ids into another NSArray)
2) Match ids in it to ids in Core Data in a single query. Return array with just the matching ids, like so:

```
-(NSArray*) findMatchInGraph:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context forResults:(NSArray*)searchResultIDs {

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity: [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Books" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

    NSPredicate *reqPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id IN %@)", searchResults;
    [request setPredicate:reqPredicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *matching = [NSMutableArray array];
    if (results) {
        for (NSManagedObject *item in results) {
            [matching addObject:[item valueForKey:@"id"]];
        }
    }
    return [matching copy];
}
```

3) TableViewController, cell for index with matching ID will add 'downloaded' indicator?

There's maybe a more efficient way of doing this.